# how to display image filename which is uploaded through fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have fileupload control to upload image in asp.net.After uploading a file, When i want to see the record I need a image with filename.How i need to get and display in front end.

Comment: Code, code and code. Please put your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `fileUpload1.FileName`?

`fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\images")+"\\"+fileUpload1.FileName);`

Comment: i am using fileupload conrtrol in one page and i want to get the filename in another page. Is it possible.?

Comment: ofcourse it is. `fileUpload1.FileName` gives you what you want.